# How do I send json back from a 403 with express

Tags: json, node.js, express

I would like to do something like the following with express.

```
let error = {errorCode:"1234"}
res.sendStatus(403, {error: error});
```

In my frontend javascript I'd like to catch the error and inspect it like so

```
getData(mydata).then((data)=> {
     console.log(data);
).catch((error)=> {
     console.log(error.errorCode);
});
```

for whatever reason this isn't sending back the json to my catch method and I'd like to know why and how I can send json when I send back a 403.

Comment: I should clarify that I am catching the 403 I'm just not seeing the error object come back. If I look in the response headers I can see my json coming back but it's not in the error object .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case , I just faced a similar case ... and found this post ... so to access the response body of a nodejs http 4xx-5xx on the client side, you can use the response.data property of the error object ...

for example in the catch block :

```
(err => console.log(JSON.stringify(err.response.data))
```

to access an object or data send in a response with a >=  400 http status
like from a nodejs server for example with

`return res.status(403).send({data});`

At least it worked for me, Hope this will help

Answer (score 4):

Use this syntax

```
res.status(403).send({errorCode:"1234"});
// or
res.status(403);
res.send({errorCode:"1234"});
```

Comment: I've tried that and all I get back is the following : Error: jsonRequest of /my/url/ failed with HTTP Error 403

Comment: Correct. Not sure why.

Comment: Json body should also come with status. How you are checking the response. In postman?

Comment: no, I'm looking in the chrome inspector at the network response.

Comment: res.status(403).send({error:{"errorCode":"1234"}}); try this